# Inserting '0' and '1' as bit using python mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a python script that attempts to insert rows into a MySQL db like so:

```
newCon = MySQLdb.connect(host="hostname", user="username", passwd="password", db="dbname")
newCur = newCon.cursor()
newCur.execute(output)
newCon.commit()
```

`output` here is a string like `INSERT INTO TableName VALUES('1','a','0')` where table structure would be something like:

```
ID INT UNSIGNED,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
active BIT NOT NULL
```

However, the script gives a warning:

```
Warning: Out of range value for column 'active' at row 1
  newCur.execute(output)
```

Is there a way to get python's mysqldb to accept 1 and 0 as values for bit columns?

Comment: Give a try to `INSERT INTO TableName VALUES(1, 'a', b'0')`

Comment: or eventually, use parameterized queries

Comment: @Cid This is a bit of a single-use script and I'm not familiar enough with python to make that happen in a generic enough manner.  As it turns out I was mistaken and the query was wrapping the bit in quotes.  I'm not sure if there is a way to make it accept '1' and '0' as bit values, but I just have the output query generate '0' and '1' without the quotes now.